# Edge options like Headless and Ignore Certificate doesn't work in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to run my script to be headless Edge and ignore the Security Certificates.
But I am getting this Error.

`if options._ignore_local_proxy:`

`AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute '_ignore_local_proxy'`

Here is my Code:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Edge
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions

Se = Service("Data\msedgedriver.exe")
options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=Se, options=options)
driver.get("https://ipsis.adm.arcor.net/gui/pl/login?func=loginmask&option=nosession")
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

**This should fix, use Selenium 4 it has integreted Edge Options Now. So update Selenium and also check url also for me it not loading...**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver import EdgeOptions

Se = Service("Data\msedgedriver.exe")
options = EdgeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=Se, options=options)
driver.get("https://ipsis.adm.arcor.net/gui/pl/login?func=loginmask&option=nosession")
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to option to code similar to yours worked for me:

```
options.accept_insecure_certs = True
```